# Any simple approaches for managing customer data change requests for global reference files?

Tags: database, database-design, data-structures

For the first time, I am developing in an environment in which there is a central repository for a number of different industry standard reference data tables and many different customers who need to select records from these industry standard reference data tables to fill in foreign key information for their customer specific records.

Because these industry standard reference files are utilized by all customers, I want to reserve Create/Update/Delete access to these records for global product administrators. However, I would like to implement a (semi-)automated interface by which specific customers could request record additions, deletions or modifications to any of the industry standard reference files that are shared among all customers.

I know I need something like a "data change request" table specifying:

user id,
user request datetime,
request type (insert, modify, delete),
a user entered text explanation of the change request,
the user request's current status (pending, declined, completed),
admin resolution datetime,
admin id,
an admin entered text description of the resolution,
etc.

What I can't figure out is how to elegantly handle the fact that these data change requests could apply to dozens of different tables with differing table column definitions. I would like to give the customer users making these data change requests a convenient way to enter their proposed record additions/modifications directly into CRUD screens that look very much like the reference table CRUD screens they don't have write/delete permissions for (with an additional text explanation and perhaps request priority field). I would also like to give the global admins a tool that allows them to view all the outstanding data change requests for the users they oversee sorted by date requested or user/date requested. Upon selecting a data change request record off the list, the admin would be directed to another CRUD screen that would be populated with the fields the customer users requested for the new/modified industry standard reference table record along with customer's text explanation, the request status and the text resolution explanation field. At this point the admin could accept/edit/reject the requested change and if accepted the affected industry standard reference file would be automatically updated with the appropriate fields and the data change request record's status, text resolution explanation and resolution datetime would all also be appropriately updated.

However, I want to keep the actual production reference tables as simple as possible and free from these extraneous and typically null customer change request fields. I'd also like the data change request file to aggregate all data change requests across all the reference tables yet somehow "point to" the specific reference table and primary key in question for modification & deletion requests or the specific reference table and associated customer user entered field values in question for record creation requests.

Does anybody have any ideas of how to design something like this effectively? Is there a cleaner, simpler way I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1

If preserving the base tables is important then I would create a "change details" table as a child to your change request table.  I'm envisioning something like

ChangeID
TableName
TableKeyValue
FieldName
ProposedValue
Add/Change/Delete Indicator

So you'd have a row in this table for every proposed field change.  The challenge in this scenario is maintaining the mapping of TableName and FieldName values to the actual tables and fields.  If your database structure if fairly static then this may not be an issue.

#### Option 2

Add a ChangeID field to each of your base tables.  When a change is proposed add a record to the base table with the ChangeID populated.  So as an example if you have a Company table, for a single company you could have multiple records:

```
CompanyCode  ChangeID  CompanyName  CompanyAddress
-----------  --------  -----------  --------------
COMP1                  My Company   Boston        <-- The "live" record
COMP1               1  New Name     Boston        <-- A proposed change
```

When the admin commits the change the existing live record is deleted or archived and the ChangeID value is removed from the proposed record making it the live record.  It may be a little tricky to handle proposed deletions with this option.  This option also has the potential for impacting performance of selecting live data for normal usage.  However it does save you the hassle of maintaining a list of table names and field names somewhere in your code.

I'm sure others will have some opinions!